# NX: Imports not working inside of a transpiled app

Tags: monorepo, nrwl-nx

I have an NX monorepo, with libs, which are all built from ESM TypeScript into ESM plain JS with SWC.

```
- libs
   - lib1
   - lib2
   - lib3
```

`lib1` imports both `lib2` and `lib3`, everything works fine before the build, but after the build when i run:

```
node dist/libs/lib1/src/main.js
```

I get the following error:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@myorg/lib2' imported from /code/dist/libs/lib1/src/main.js
```

In a previous monorepo project that used lerna, i was able to take advantage of module hoisting, which as far as i understand it was creating a symlink inside of node_modules, pointing to the compiled version. What solution do I have to replicate this behavior in nx and get node import working? It works in my frontend app because of bundling, but i'd rather not go down that route for a node app.

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, i've ended up using this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm-module-alias?activeTab=versions

With a custom function that reads the tsconfig and points each library to its location within `dist`:

```
import generateAliasesResolver from "esm-module-alias"
import tsconfig from "tsconfig.base.json" assert { type: "json" }

const aliases = {}
Object.entries(tsconfig.compilerOptions.paths).forEach(([libName, libPath]) => {
  aliases[libName] =
    libPath[0]
      .replace("/src/index.ts", "")
      .replace("libs/", "dist/libs/")
})

export const resolve = generateAliasesResolver(aliases)
```

And then i run it with:

```
node --loader ./path-to-script.mjs --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --no-warnings dist/.../script.js
```